# Automorphism of trees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, automorphism-group

First of all I am sorry to include an image but am not sure how to post this otherwise.

I am having some trouble understanding what constitutes an automorphsim of a graph. let's consider the top left tree and mark its vertices starting from the upper leaf and continuing clockwise (with the graph) as ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$. so according to this solution the only automorphisms are $\sigma(i) = i $, and $\sigma(1) = 6, \sigma(6) = 1, \sigma(i)_{2 \leq i \leq 5} = i$.

Why isn't $\sigma(3) = 4, \sigma(4) = 3, \sigma(i)_{\text{else}} = i$ also an automorphsim? it holds $(i, j) \in E$ iff $ (\sigma(i), \sigma(j))\in E_{new}$, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: "$\sigma(1) = 6, \sigma(6) = 1, \sigma(i)_{2 \leq i \leq 5} = i$"  is not an automorphism. You need to take $\sigma(i)=7-i$.

Comment: @JohnB I see, I guess I misunderstood it. Why isn't it an automorphism then?

Comment: Because it doesn't satisfy the definition of automorphism. What is your definition anyways? If it is the one in your question (which is correct), you just need to check that it fails for some $i$.

Comment: @JohnB I wrote it (last paragraph). Is it not correct?

Comment: Okay I think I understand my mistake (misunderstood the definition). Thanks.